# How to select <html> element using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the  element using javascript without using its ID( html id="somethin" ) or a class.

Something like.....

```
var whatIWantedToSelect = document.html;
```

OR
Something like.....

```
var whatIWantedToSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
```

Please, see the below picture to see the exact DOM element that I want to access via javascript.

[image: The DOM element that I want to select]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> var whatIWantedToSelect = document.html;

The HTML element is the `document.documentElement`.

> var whatIWantedToSelect = document.getElementsByName('html')[0];

`getElementsByName` matches elements by their `name` **attribute**. You are looking for `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 5):

The root `<html>` element is available as `document.documentElement`. So there is no need to select it by tag name (which would have worked too, but you had `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementsByTagName`).

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

```js
var whatIWantedToSelect = document.documentElement
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` function as follows:

```js
let html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
console.log(html);
html.addEventListener("click",function(){
     console.log("clicked")
})

html.click();
```

```html
<html></html>
```

Comment: but my event listener is not working when document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].click(); called. But if I clicked somewhere b mouse it works, Why?